# Entry dentro de un LabelFrame queda desacomodado al agregar un Button

Tags: python

```
Hará 2 meses que empecé a ver Python. Estoy usando tkinter para realizar una aplicación de escritorio. Tengo un problema de acomodamiento de widgets dentro de un labelframe. El código de abajo:

from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Acomodar Entry en LabelFrame")
root.geometry("340x180")

#Creo el LabelFrame
lfs=LabelFrame(root,width=200,height=200,text=" Título ")
lfs.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,ipady=10,ipadx=10,sticky="we")

#Creo la etiqueta
lbl = Label(lfs, text="Label")
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="w")

#Creo el Entry
txt = Entry(lfs, width=12)
txt.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

muestra la siguiente imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Ahi se ve el label acomodado a la izquierda, con el Entry muy cerca del label.
Ahora si a ese código le agrego las siguientes líneas antes del root.MainLoop():

btnAceptar = Button(lfs, text="Aceptar", width=10)
btnAceptar.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=4,padx=5,sticky="w")

btnSalir = Button(lfs, text="Salir", width=10, command=root.destroy)
btnSalir.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=4,padx=5,sticky="w")
```

la imágen que me muestra es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi se ve que el Entry se va como más a la derecha.
¿ Cómo puedo hacer que el Entry quede como estaba antes de agregar los Button?``

Answer (score 0):

## Explicación

.grid se maneja en columnas y filas. Piensa en grid como una planilla de Excel y en los widgets como valores que ubicas en celda. Tu programa muestra la geometria de la ventana de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que buscas es que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrás ver, algo estaría funcionando mal con mi Excel si eso fuera posible (la imagen está editada), por lo que grid simplemente no permitiría hacer lo que buscas (o eso es lo que creo).

## Solución

Puedes hacer que el entry y los botones estén en dos frames separados y luego ubicar dichos frames:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Acomodar Entry en LabelFrame")
root.geometry("340x180")

#------------------------------------------#
# creo el LabelFrame                       #
#------------------------------------------#
lfs=LabelFrame(root,width=200,height=200,text=" Título ")
lfs.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,ipady=10,ipadx=10,sticky="we")


#------------------------------------------#
# creo el frame que tendrá el entry        #
#------------------------------------------#
entry_frame = Frame(lfs)

#Creo la etiqueta
lbl = Label(entry_frame, text="Label")
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="w")

#Creo el Entry
txt = Entry(entry_frame, width=12)
txt.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

# ubico el frame.
entry_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")



#------------------------------------------#
# creo el frame que tendrá los botones     #
#------------------------------------------#
button_frame = Frame(lfs)

btnAceptar = Button(button_frame, text="Aceptar", width=10)
btnAceptar.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=4,padx=5,sticky="w")

btnSalir = Button(button_frame, text="Salir", width=10, command=root.destroy)
btnSalir.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=4,padx=5,sticky="w")

button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
```

Esto si lo vemos en el Excel tiene la estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 0

Muchas Gracias Dante, muy buena explicación, antes de publicar la pregunta habia probado de varias formas y no le encontraba la vuelta. Gracias

Comment: Un placer Antonio c: